# Visual Studio Code Feature

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I was wondering is there any plugin that can make Visual Studio Code auto-import class that needed in the code when we type it ?

I'm studying Laravel right now and know if PHPStorm could do that.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MehediDracula.php-namespace-resolver)? It's not automatic but might help.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+X 
the are lots of extension  that can help you with that